# Обновление диаграммы при изменении свойств графиков (vue-chartjs)

Tags: vue.js, chart.js

По умолчанию при построении диаграммы к каждому из линейных графиков добавляется легенда. При клике на легенду диаграммы соответствующий график скрывается или показывается на диаграмме. Пример диаграммы с отключенным графиком:

[image: пример диаграммы с отключенным графиком]

Но хотелось бы реализовать данный функционал совместно с мульти-селектом, который представляет из себя набор *checkbox*. Каждый из *checkbox* соответствует одному из линейных графиков на диаграмме.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false


import Vue from 'vue'
import {
  Line
} from 'vue-chartjs'

Vue.component('my-line', {
  extends: Line,
  props: ['data', 'options'],
  mounted() {
    this.renderChart(this.data, this.options)
  }
})

const Chart = {
  template: `<div id="app" class="relative flex items-center">
    <my-line
      v-if="showLine"
      :width="700"
      :height="300"
      :styles="{position: 'relative'}"
      :options="options"
      :data="lineData"
    ></my-line>
  </div>`,
  name: 'chart',
  data() {
    return {
      showLine: false,
      position: "relative",
      options: {
        responsive: false,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        tooltips: {
          enabled: false,
          custom: false
        },
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
              display: false,
              color: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)"
            },
            ticks: {
              fontFamily: "Montserrat"
            }
          }],
          yAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
              display: false,
              color: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)"
            },
            ticks: {
              display: false,
              fontFamily: "Montserrat"
            }
          }]
        }
      },
      lineData: {
        labels: [
          "Янв",
          "Фев",
          "Мар",
          "Апр",
          "Май",
          "Июн",
          "Июл",
          "Авг",
          "Сен",
          "Окт",
          "Ноя",
          "Дек"
        ],
        datasets: [{
            label: "one",
            lineTension: 0,
            fill: false,
            borderColor: "#466FFF",
            backgroundColor: "#ffffff00",
            data: [20, 35, 14, 15, 45, 38, 35, 50, 30, 36, 18, 20]
          },
          {
            label: "two",
            lineTension: 0,
            fill: false,
            borderColor: "#FF4286",
            backgroundColor: "#ffffff00",
            data: [30, 45, 24, 25, 55, 48, 45, 60, 40, 46, 28, 30]
          },
          {
            label: "three",
            lineTension: 0,
            fill: false,
            borderColor: "#31DDA9",
            backgroundColor: "#ffffff00",
            data: [40, 55, 34, 35, 65, 58, 55, 70, 50, 56, 38, 40]
          }
        ]
      }
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.showLine = true;
  },
  computed: {
    myStyles() {
      return {
        position: "relative"
      };
    }
  }
}

const Multi = {
  template: `<div class="dropdown relative font-semibold cursor-pointer" @mouseenter="over_element=true"
    @mouseleave="over_element=false">
    <div @click.stop="toggle_dropdown" :class="[ active ? 'add-shadow rounded-top' : 'rounded-full']"
        class="multiStyles heading">
        <p>{{selected_names || placeholder}}</p>
        <div style="padding-right: 16.5px;">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div v-show="active" :class="[ active ? 'add-shadow' : '' ]" class="options">
        <div class="option multiOption" v-for="(option, idx) in temp_options" :key="idx"
            @click.stop="select_option(idx)">
            <checkbox :checked="option.checked" class="multiCheck" />
            <p class="multiP">{{option.name}}</p>
            <div class="colorBox"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`,
  name: 'multi',
  components: {
    'checkbox': Checkbox,
  },
  props: {
    options: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    },
    placeholder: {
      type: String,
      default: 'Select',
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.temp_options = this.options;
    this.temp_options.forEach((item) => {
      item.checked = false;
    })
  },
  data() {
    return {
      active: false,
      selected: [],
      over_element: false,
      temp_options: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggle_dropdown() {
      this.active = !this.active;
    },
    close() {
      if (this.active) {
        this.active = false;
      }
    },
    set_selected(event) {
      this.selected.name = event.name;
      this.selected.value = event.value;
    },
    select_option(idx) {
      let index = this.selected.findIndex((item) => item.value === this.options[idx].value);

      if (index >= 0) {
        this.temp_options[idx].checked = false;
        this.selected.splice(index, 1);
      } else {

        this.temp_options[idx].checked = true;
        this.selected.push(this.options[idx]);
      }
    },
    computed: {
      selected_names() {
        return this.selected.map((item) => item.name).join(', ');
      }
    },
    watch: {
      selected() {
        this.$emit('input', this.selected);
      }
    }
  }
}

const Checkbox = {
  template: `
 <label class="check-container"><slot class="pt-1" />
    <input type="checkbox" @change="$emit('inut', check)" :checked="check" @click="check=!check">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>`,
  name: 'checkbox',
  props: {
    checked: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.check = this.checked;
  },
  data() {
    return {
      check: '',
    }
  },
  watch: {
    checked() {
      this.check = this.checked;
    }
  }
};

const App = {
  template: `
    <multi
        class="multiWidth"
        :options="options_example2"
        :placeholder="placeholder"
        v-model="selected"
    /> 
    <chart></chart>`,
  components: {
    'multi': Multi,
    'chart': Chart
  },
  data() {
    return {
      options_example2: [{
          value: 0,
          name: "one"
        },
        {
          value: 1,
          name: "two"
        },
        {
          value: 2,
          name: "three"
        }
      ],
      placeholder: " "
    }
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    App
  },
  template: `<app></app>`
})
```

```css
.multiWidth {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
}

.multiStyles {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  background: white;
  padding-top: 0.75rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.75rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-left: 4px;
}

.multiStyles p {
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.heading {
  max-height: 43px !important;
}

.multiStyles div {
  margin-left: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.rounded-full {
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.rounded-top {
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
}

.options {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 100;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.option {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 500;
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 4;
}

.multiOption {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.options .option:hover {
  background: gray;
}

.multiCheck {
  margin-top: -1.5rem;
}

.multiP {
  margin-left: -0.25rem;
}

.rotate {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.add-shadow {
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px rgba(96, 90, 107, 0.18);
}

.check-container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.check-container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4.5px;
  left: 0;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #DCD8E3;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}

.check-container:hover .checkmark::after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
}

.check-container::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.check-container input:checked~.checkmark::after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
}

.check-container .checkmark::after {
  left: 5px;
  top: 2px;
  width: 4px;
  height: 8px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.colorBox {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak></div>

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-chartjs/3.4.2/vue-chartjs.js'></script>
```

---

Как обновить диаграмму при изменении графиков?

Comment: я новичок, не судите строго мое написание кода и вопроса здесь. Картинки прилагаю для визулизации

Comment: @РустамГимранов, dropdownmenu с множественным выбором (не одно значение, а несколько можно выбирать)

Comment: @РустамГимранов прикрепила код!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Основная суть: при изменении свойств каждого из объектов массива наблюдатель запускает метод пересчета свойств линейных графиков и обновления диаграммы.

Краткий пример из [документации](https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#own-watcher):

```
watch: {
  chartData () {
    this.$data._chart.update();
  }
}
```

В качестве примера за основу взят ваш код, но многое упразднено, чтобы не пробрасывать массив отмеченных *checkbox*. Демо:

```js
// import Vue from 'vue'
// import {
//     Line
// } from 'vue-chartjs'

const {
  Line,
  // mixins: reactiveProp,
  // mixins: reactiveData,
} = VueChartJs;

Vue.component('my-line', {
  extends: Line,
  // mixins: [reactiveProp, reactiveData],
  props: {
    chartData: {
      type: Object,
      default: null
    },
    options: {
      type: Object,
      default: null
    },
    selected: {
      type: Array,
      default: [],
    }
  },

  data() {
    return {
      selectedWatcher: null,
      lineData: this.chartData
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    // При монтировании компонента строим диаграмму.
    this.renderChart(this.lineData, this.options);

    // Устанавливаем наблюдателя за массивом отмеченных `checkbox`.
    this.selectedWatcher = this.$watch('selected', this.updateChart, {
      deep: true
    });
  },

  methods: {
    updateChart(newVal) {
      // Для демо использована эта конструкция, но
      // возможно в ваших проектах нужно использовать.
      // В частности, при возникновении ошибки:
      // > cannot read property 'update' of undefined
      // const chart = this.$data._chart;

      const chart = this._chart;

      // Составим массив из имен отмеченных `checkbox`.
      const selected = this.$props.selected
        .map((item) => item.checked && item.name);

      // Преобразуем локальное свойство,
      // обновив каждому из графиков свойство,
      // отвечающее за отображение.
      this.lineData = {
        ...this.$props.chartData,
        datasets: this.$props.chartData.datasets
          .forEach((item) => {
            item.hidden = !selected.includes(item.label)
          })
      }

      // Обновляем диаграмму.
      chart.update();
    }
  }
});

const Chart = {
  name: 'chart',
  props: {
    selected: {
      type: Array,
      default: [],
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      height: 300,
      showLine: false,
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        legend: {
          display: false,
        }
      },
      lineData: {
        labels: [
          "Янв", "Фев", "Мар", "Апр", "Май", "Июн",
          "Июл", "Авг", "Сен", "Окт", "Ноя", "Дек"
        ],
        datasets: [{
          hidden: false,
          label: "one",
          lineTension: 0,
          fill: false,
          borderColor: "#466FFF",
          backgroundColor: "#ffffff00",
          data: [20, 35, 14, 15, 45, 38, 35, 50, 30, 36, 18, 20]
        }, {
          hidden: false,
          label: "two",
          lineTension: 0,
          fill: false,
          borderColor: "#FF4286",
          backgroundColor: "#ffffff00",
          data: [30, 45, 24, 25, 55, 48, 45, 60, 40, 46, 28, 30]
        }, {
          hidden: false,
          label: "three",
          lineTension: 0,
          fill: false,
          borderColor: "#31DDA9",
          backgroundColor: "#ffffff00",
          data: [40, 55, 34, 35, 65, 58, 55, 70, 50, 56, 38, 40]
        }]
      }
    };
  },
  computed: {
    styles() {
      return {
        position: 'relative'
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.showLine = true;
  },
  template: `
    <div class="relative flex items-center">
        <my-line
          v-if="showLine"
          :width="700"
          :height="300"
          :styles="styles"
          :options="options"
          :chart-data="lineData"
          :selected="selected"
        ></my-line>
    </div>`,
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    'chart': Chart
  },
  data: {
    selected: [{
      "name": "one",
      "checked": true
    }, {
      "name": "two",
      "checked": true
    }, {
      "name": "three",
      "checked": true
    }]
  }
});
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <template v-for="checkbox in selected">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" v-model="checkbox.checked" /> {{ checkbox.name }}</label>
  </template>

  <chart :selected="selected"></chart>

  <pre>{{ selected }}</pre>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-chartjs@2.8.7/dist/vue-chartjs.full.min.js"></script>
```

---

На основе данного примера вы сможете уже нарастить необходимый функционал.

Comment: спасибо! Стала реализовывать это внутри своего проекта, консоль выдает ошибку при клике на чекбокс "cannot read property 'update' of undefined"...Что это может быть? Как можно это исправить?

Comment: да, вы все верно поняли, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Были непредсказуемые глюки пришлось изменить чуть код используя https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#getdatasetmetaindex

```
  methods: {
    updateChart(newVal) {
      // Для демо использована эта конструкция, но
      // возможно в ваших проектах нужно использовать.
      // В частности, при возникновении ошибки:
      // > cannot read property 'update' of undefined
      // const chart = this.$data._chart;

      const chart = this._chart;

      // Составим массив из имен отмеченных `checkbox`.
      const selected = this.$props.selected
        .map((item) => item.checked && item.name);

    // перебираем датасеты
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataSet, i) => {
    // волшебная функция получения мета данных по датасету
    var meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(i); 
    // если метка не входит в список избранных то hidden=true иначе false
    meta.hidden = !selected.includes(dataSet.label);
  });
  

      // Обновляем диаграмму.
      chart.update();
    }
  }
});
```